# Hide connection to points outside x-range in Highcharts line chart type

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, line

When using the "line" chart type in Highcharts and specifing a specific range for the x-axis that results in only part of the series being visible the outside data points still show liens to the previous and next data points (that are not visible).

Is there a way to hide those connections (as if the points outside the displayed range wouldn't exist)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zones` to create transparent lines between the point that is visible and the point that is not.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/h8xmmbLe/